# Role based controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My MVC application is dual-purpose and provides pretty much exactly the same functionality in both modes.

The `Index` view provides a set of search options via a drop-down 
, with the exception that some of the options available are restricted.

On my controller I need to route to a different `Index()` action based on the `[Authorize]` setting. NB: Roles based on Active Directory Groups

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Admin")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}

[Authorize(Roles = @"User")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}
```

Obviously, this isn't going to work as there's two identical method signatures so wont compile.

The next option to use different method names

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Admin")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexADMIN()
{
}

[Authorize(Roles = @"User")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult IndexUSER()
{
}
```

...but that then mean one of the modes would have to explicitly have the view/controller action in the URL (well, that's my understanding).

One final option would be to just change the signature of one of the methods and add a dummy parameter that is ignored but its not very elegant!

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"Admin")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
}

[Authorize(Roles = @"User")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(bool Dummy)
{
}
```

Comment: What if you create one method and check user role *inside* of action method ?

Comment: That is another option - but I was wondering if MVC 4 could be a bit more clever about it

Comment: ...but would that work on Nested AD Groups

Comment: Still, it doesn't allow two ambiguous methods with same signature, may be it's better to group it by controller and not by action methods. You can create one controller for admin requests and another for users one

Comment: do you want both roles on index action?

Comment: In this link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application you could see the lifecycle of a request in MVC.  Perhaps you could override some member or add a filter, to forward the request with the same URL to the correct actiion.

Comment: You can do this a "clever" way in MVC with the use of a `ActionNameSelectorAttribute`.   Read more about it on a (semi-related) question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33169654/2181514