# multiple submit form in html beginform mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.beginform

Trying to make multiple submit form, but having error `The current request for action 'EditAccount' on controller type 'AccountController is ambiguous between the following action methods`. How can i fix this? Here's code

Attribute:

```
public class HttpParamActionAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        if (actionName.Equals(methodInfo.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        var request = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        return request[methodInfo.Name] != null;
    }
}
```

Methods from controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpParamAction]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> AddNew(AccountModel model)
{ ... }


[HttpPost]
[HttpParamAction]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> EditAccount(AccountModel model)
{ ... }
```

And view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new {@class = "form-horizontal"}))
{

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" name="EditAccount">Save</button>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" name="AddNew" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add New</button>

}
```

Comment: I guessing your not understanding what your method parameters are or what your buttons are doing (and they need `value` attributes in order to post a value). Suggest you look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970159/net-mvc4-actionnameselectorattribute-multiple-buttons-within-view-is-not-workin)

Comment: I think this article will have the answer for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, It will work. Basis on `name` and `value` call the function.

`.cshtml`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName",new {@class = "form-horizontal"}))
{

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" name="Account" value="Edit">Save</button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-w-m btn-primary" name="Account" value="AddNew" ><i class="fa fa-plus" ></i>&nbsp;Add New</button>

}
```

`.cs`

```
[HttpPost]
[HttpParamAction]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> ActionName(AccountModel model, string Account)
{ 
  if(Account=="Edit"){
   ... 
  }
  else if(Account=="AddNew"){
    ....
  }
}
```